# Один счетчик для всех страниц в виджете vk.like

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Ситуация такая: был поставлен на сайт виджет "ВК.МнеНравится".

Там автоматом вставляется урл страницы, на которой он находится и поэтому получается, что для каждой страницы - разный счетчик...

Как исправить это СЕЙЧАС? Потому что поставить параметр `page_id = УРЛ_ГЛАВНАЯ` недостаточно, потому как это приводит к обнулению счетчика (видать я не попадаю или указываю неверно страницу).

Цитата с контакта

> Идентификатор страницы на Вашем сайте.
> Целое 32хразрядное число. Используется
> в том случае, если у одной и той же
> статьи может быть несколько адресов, а
> также на динамических сайтах, у
> которых меняется только хеш. Значение
> по умолчанию - контрольная сумма от
> location.href.

Вопрос, собственно, в том, как вк.лайк генерирует этот `page_id`, чтобы подставить туда ид главной (чтоб для всех страниц был счетчик главной) - ну и собственно решить проблему

Приведите пожалста формулу (на php для смарти)

```
{php}echo crc32('http://мойсайт.ru/');{/php}
```

не работает.

Comment: никто не знает?

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос. Как считается этот page_id по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, тебе может пригодиться вот это:

> Если кому еще интересно, столкнулся с такой же проблемой, был домен site1.ru на нем было 5к коментариев, потом сайт переехал на домен site2.ru, проблема вся решилась сохранием опенапи.js на свой сайт и заменой пару строк, `pData.url` на `pData.url.replace("site2.ru","site1.ru")`, в итого на новом сайте подгружаем старые комментарии.

По аналогии ты можешь сделать также:

```
pData.url.replace(location.href, "site.ru");
```

Comment: ты не понял) или я не понял. мне заменять то впринципе не надо. мне надо вставить один и тот же урл на лайк счетчик...
я пробую ставить адрес сайта (с/без  www http://  /) ничего не помогает, вот я и думаю как узнать page_id главной страницы чтоб его вставить фиксированно в шаблон и все. потому как мне нужен лайк один на всех страницах